# When are both $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \log(a_n)$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I'm new to this site. Can someone give me some examples of when both:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \log(a_n)\qquad \text{ and }\qquad \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$$
are convergent?

Comment: I have the same question that Jack has, but I assumed in my edit that you wrote that part by mistake.

Comment: $a_n$ and $\log a_n$ cannot converge to 0 simultaneously, so they cannot converge together in the ordinary sense.

Comment: Perhaps you want to look at $\log(1 + a_n)$ instead

Comment: ... in such a case, by taking $a_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$, we have: $$\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n = \frac{\pi^2}{6},\qquad \sum_{n\geq 0}\log(1+a_n)=\log\sinh \pi-\log\pi.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can never happen.  If $a_n$ does not converge to $1$, then the first sum diverges.  If $a_n$ does not converge to $0$, then the second sum diverges.  One of these two must always occur.

Answer (score 4):

There are no sequences for which that happens. A necessary condition for the convergence of a series is that the general term is $o(1)$. Hence by assuming that both your series are converging we have $a_n\to 0$ as well as $a_n\to 1$, contradiction.